# Delete every inactive data SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to delete every data from every table in a specific schema that satisfy the condition to be inactive. Active/inactive value is a boolean that every table has this column.

How do I do this?

Comment: You are asking for a solution without showing your own effort or even information about your schema.

Comment: This question sounds perfect to me. I can't see why so many votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_inactive_records()
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
DECLARE VTABLES     RECORD; 
    VRESULT     TEXT;
    VNUM_ROWS   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    VRESULT = '';
    FOR VTABLES IN  (
            select distinct table_schema || '.' || table_name as table_name
            from   information_schema.tables t 
            where   exists  (
                    select  1 
                    from    information_schema.columns c 
                    where   c.table_catalog = t.table_catalog 
                    and     c.table_schema = c.table_schema 
                    and     c.table_name = t.table_name 
                    and     c.column_name = 'active'
                    and     t.table_catalog in ("<your_table_catalog1>", "<your_table_catalog2>", "<etc>")
                    )
            order   by 1
            )
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'DELETING FROM %...', VTABLES.TABLE_NAME;
        EXECUTE ('DELETE FROM ' || VTABLES.TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE active = 0');
        get diagnostics vNUM_ROWS = ROW_COUNT;
        VRESULT = VRESULT || vNUM_ROWS || ' records were deleted from ' || VTABLES.TABLE_NAME || chr(13);       
    END LOOP;
    return VRESULT;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

And then call `select delete_inactive_records();` any time you want to "clean-up" your tables!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just do this magically you need to write a query to create your query.

Something like this :

```
select distinct tablename from information_schema.columns where columnname = 'Active'
```

would give you a list of tables then just add that into a query that says

```
delete from <tablename> where active = 0
```